# PowerShell Import-CSV, For Each Item, Delete String After Symbol

Tags: string, powershell, csv

If you have a list like this:

```
User1.XXXX
User2.XXXXX
User3.XXX
```

How can you create a for each loop and delete everything after the period? Also how do you delete everything before as well? I only have the basics written, and tried a few misguided attempts manipulating it with .substring etc...:

```
$allUsers = Import-Csv -path "c:\Folder1\All User.csv"
$allUsers | foreach {

} | Export-Csv -Path "c:\Folder1\Removed.csv"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way in this case would be to use Split method:

```
$allUsers = Get-Content somepath | foreach {
    $_.Split('.')[0]
} | Set-Content somepath
```

[0] is taking the first element from the array of elements created by Split, in your case there would be 2 elements, everything before the dot and everything after the dot. You could take everything after the dot with [1] instead of [0].
Also, you do not want to use Import-Csv since in this case it would be easier to work with raw data.

edit: since I'm not sure what your actual CSV looks like you might want to use something like this:

```
$data = Import-CSV somepath
$results = @()
foreach ($line in $data) {
    $line.Column_that_needs_editing = $line.Column_that_needs_editing.Split('.')[0]
    $results += $_
}

$results | Export-CSV someotherpath
```

Comment: You should change `$_` to `$line` in the second script. And in case there is no header include a `-header H1,H2` to the import-csv

Comment: thanks, i'll do it, but it will work with $_ also ;) as for the headers, thats up to the author, as I have no clue what and how many of them are there.

Comment: You guys are a godsend! The simple script works! I only have 1 column with no header atm. Just a quick question. The name of the variable $line in 'foreach ($line in $data) can really be any variable name right?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Did you test that? Here $results is empty when using `$_`

Comment: Yes, DrixlRey, it doesnt really matter. ``$something in $somethingelse``